# How to print out the keys of an array like $_POST in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays

Maybe the code looks like something like this:

```
foreach(...$POST){
echo $key."<br/>;
}
```

Comment: This question has been asked numerous times before.

Comment: like here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/693637/output-echo-print-everything-from-a-php-array

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
var_dump($_POST);
```

or

```
print_r($_POST);
```

You might insert a pre tag before and after for the clearer output in your browser:

```
echo '<pre>';
var_dump($_POST);
echo '</pre>';
```

And I suggest to use [Xdebug](http://xdebug.org/). It provides an enchanted var_dump that works without pre's as well.

Comment: This is the best way to do it, use some `<pre>...</pre>` tags around it for better formatting.

Comment: Additionally, if he only wants the keys, `array_keys()` will do it.

Comment: You could also do print nl2br(print_r($_POST)); (replace $_POST with the name of your array) to avoid having to bother with the pre tags.

Answer (score 3):

See the PHP documentation on foreach:
http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php

Your code would look something like this:

```
foreach ($_POST as $key=>$element) {
   echo $key."<br/>";
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Tested one liner:

```
echo join('<br />',array_keys($_POST));
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do something with them programmatically (eg turn them into a list or table), just loop:

```
foreach ($_POST as $k => $v) {
  echo $k . "<br>";
}
```

For debugging purposes:

```
print_r($_POST);
```

or

```
var_dump($_POST);
```

Answer (score 0):

And if you want full coverage of the whole array, `print_r` or even more detailed `var_dump`

Answer (score 0):

```
$array = array_flip($array);
echo implode('any glue between array keys',$array);
```

Comment: NB: I'm assuming you don't just want to do this for debug purposes. Otherwise print_r, var_dump, var_export etc are good choices.

Answer (score 0):

Or you could just print out the array keys:

```
foreach (array_keys($_POST) as $key) {
    echo "$key<br/>\n";
}
```

Comment: This answers the question exactly but received a down-vote.  Down-voter care to add a comment?  Obviously, the '<br/>\n' could be dropped but was provided for formatting.

Comment: I didn't want my comment to be a reason for other people to downvote that... it's just bad PHP-style thats all. No reason to downing...

Comment: Well, not to escape variables is bad style IMHO. No matter what kind of variables, they should always be escaped.

Comment: Wow, your response makes no sense.  Escaping the contents of a variable for inserting into SQL (from a post) to prevent SQL injection makes sense, and there are other reasons that you would want to escape a variable.  But just for examining the contents of an array, it is entirely unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

Normally I would use `print_r($_POST)`.

If using within an HTML page, it's probably worth wrapping in a `<pre>` tag to get a better looking output, otherwise the useful tabs and line breaks only appear in source view.

[print_r() on PHP.net](http://www.php.net/print_r)