# Wierd php array? after db query

Tags: php, arrays

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Output (echo/print) everything from a PHP Array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/693637/output-echo-print-everything-from-a-php-array)

I have done a query from a database and the result is stored in a variable which is believe is an array. The output is only one row and column so i use:

```
echo result[0];
```

to output the result.
However i get an error saying:

```
Notice: Array to string conversion in "C:/apache/htdocs...."
array
```

I tried to dump the variable using

```
var_dump result[0];
```

I then get this

```
array(1) { [0]=> array(1) { ["var_datain"]=> string(4) "hai!" } }
```

So.... how do i get it to echo out the value ***hai!*** from that array?

In case it matters, here is my query

```
    $db = new PDO(DSN, DBUSER, DBPASS);
    $stmt = $db->prepare("CALL test(?)");
    $parameter = 'hai!';
    $stmt->bindValue(1, $parameter, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $rs = $stmt->execute();
    $result = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    var_dump($result);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a multidimensional array.

```
echo $result[0]['var_datain'];
```

It depends of the way you did your query (show us more code to explain you better) but it looks that in your case each line returned by your query is another array containing the columns that you selected. Even if you select only one col and only one row, it's still returned as a multidimensional array.

Got it?

Comment: awesome! but i should be also able to do $result[0][0] right? coz im refering to its indexes but i get an error:

Notice: Undefined offset: 0

Comment: @VidhuShresthBhatnagar You are doing an associative fetch via `PDO::FETCH_ASSOC`, so you will not receive numeric keys back, only the associative keys from column names. You must therefore use `$result[0]['var_datain']`.

Comment: Edit: If you want to use `$result[0][0]` put `PDO::FETCH_NUM` instead of `PDO::FETCH_ASSOC`. You can also use `PDO::FETCH_BOTH` that will return both `$result[0][0]` and `$result[0]['var_datain']`

Comment: hi, i just did array_values($result), i could then do $result[0][0] but ill change over to using PDO::FETCH_NUM. Thanks Phius