# I am trying to use substr to extract the part of the array element value with a if-else statement

Tags: php, if-statement, substr

I am really new to PHP and am having some trouble on how to output this.

```
$employee_numbers = array( "Sam Jerry"=>"1849", "David Flint"=>"2274", "Lena Vincent"=>"2532", Robert Vanny"=>"3471" );
```

I am trying to output it so that the substr shows the Name and number.

So it looks something like this:

**Sam Jerry's** employee number is: **1849** --> MANAGEMENT

Comment: try this https://ideone.com/M1toN2

Comment: possible duplicate of [Output (echo/print) everything from a PHP Array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/693637/output-echo-print-everything-from-a-php-array)

Answer (score 1):

You have to loop through the array.

```
$employee_numbers = array( "Sam Jerry"=>"1849", "David Flint"=>"2274", "Lena Vincent"=>"2532", "Robert Vanny"=>"3471" );

foreach($employee_numbers as $employee => $number){
   echo $employee . " employee number is: " .$number . PHP_EOL; //Don't know where the management info is
}
```

Answer (score 0):

@Marcos is correct if you're showing all the member of that array. If you want Sam *specifically*, you can either throw an if clause inside your iterator, or use something like this method which pulls some voodoo with grepping to access directly via regular expression.

Either way, substr is not what you want here. That's for pulling out parts of strings: like getting "am Jer" from "Sam Jerry".

*forgive me, I copied this directly from a project I'm on right now :)*

Your usage might be something like `$result = grep_array('/Sam Jerry/', $employee_numbers);`

```
/**
 * Searches an array for keys that match a rex pattern, and returns those as a new array.
 * example:
 * all global email accounts are stored in the config under the keys
 * 'site.email.$accountid.name', and have a matching 'site.email.$accountid.address'
 * to get an array of [$accountid] => (email, name) :
 *   $grepNames = preg_grep_keys("/site\.email\..*\.name/", $config); will return all the name nodes.
 * walk $grepNames, exploding the keys and pulling [2], which is the $accountid.
 *   preg_grep_keys("/site\.email\.($accountId)\.address/", $config); will match the address node for that accountId
 * the first element of its return will contain the config node.
 *
 * internally, it uses @see preg_grep() for searching.
 *
 * I deprecated calls to get_site_config() in favor the single $config instance when Sarah put it in place
 *
 * @param $pattern string rex pattern to mathch.
 * @param $input array the array to search. generally, this will be the global config.
 * @param int $flags @see preg_grep()
 * @return array elements that match the provided $pattern
 */
function grep_array($pattern, $input = null, $flags = 0)
{
  global $config;
  if ($input === null) {
    $input = $config['fields'];
  }
  return array_intersect_key(
      $input,
      array_flip(preg_grep($pattern, array_keys($input), $flags))
  );
}
```